# Android Emulator not working in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

I tried to run the application in android studio. The Device / Emulator is launched but the screen of the device does not proceed beyond the word "Android" showing on it. The message log shown is "Device Connected: emulator-5554". I am trying to run a new application with no major code.

Can you please help?

OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Create a new device and try again. Possibly try android 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and here are 2 easy fixes...

Fix 1: Download a different android emulator like [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) or [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/),

Fix 2 (Untested): You need to add more ram to the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below video for the solution

[Ubuntu Android Emulator not working, kvm not found: Solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBqdDJbCTNA)